# No vector when Using spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')?

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

After running this

```py
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
has_vector = nlp('test text').has_vector
# ...
...has_vector == True
```

But after running this

```py
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
has_vector = nlp('test text').has_vector
# ...
...has_vector == False
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You asked this on the spaCy forums too, but the Transformer pipelines don't include word vectors because you generally don't need them if you have Transformers. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/9076

Comment: If you'd like to post this as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs here (https://spacy.io/usage/embeddings-transformers) though, you can get the vector using

```
nlp('test text')._.trf_data.tensors[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`has_vector` refers to word vectors specifically, and not contextual vectors generated by Transformers. Since if you're using Transformers you generally don't need word vectors, the spaCy Transformers pipeline doesn't include word vectors, which is why you get this result.